# UIRefreshControl does not work correctly

Tags: ios, swift, uirefreshcontrol

The refresh wheel stops at 95% full, and the refresh will only work if from the very top of the screen you reach the bottom.

```
lazy var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl = {
    let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action:
       #selector(VFeedVC.refresh(_:)),
                            for: .valueChanged)
    return refreshControl
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.tableView.addSubview(refreshControl)
}

func refresh(_ sender: Any) {
    Metric.sendEvent("RefreshFeed")
    self.refreshControl.beginRefreshing()
    self.getFeeds(self.user.id)
}

func getFeeds(_ userId: Int) {
    VNetwork.getFeeds(userId) { feeds in
        self.feeds = feeds
        self.tableView.isHidden = self.feeds.count == 0
        self.configureCells()
        self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me on iOS 11:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.tableView.refreshControl = refreshControl
    self.tableView.addSubview(refreshControl)
}
```

Also, you don't need to explicitly tell the refresh control to begin refreshing, so this is enough:

```
func refresh(_ sender: Any) {
    Metric.sendEvent("RefreshFeed")
    self.getFeeds(self.user.id)
}
```

Also make sure that in the callback for `VNetwork.getFeeds(userId) { feeds in` you are on the main thread.

Comment: This problem was if in storyboard your viewController has "freeform" option. Turn on to fixed size of ViewController, it's help to me

Answer (score 0):

with `self.tableView.refreshControl = refreshControl`you can add the refreshControl directly to the tableview, also you don't have to call `self.refreshControl.beginRefreshing()`

```
lazy var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl = {
   let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
   refreshControl.addTarget(self, action:
       #selector(VFeedVC.refresh(_:)),
                            for: .valueChanged)
   return refreshControl
}()
override func viewDidLoad() {

self.tableView.refreshControl = refreshControl
self.tableView.addSubview(refreshControl)
}
func refresh(_ sender: Any) {
    Metric.sendEvent("RefreshFeed")
    self.getFeeds(self.user.id)
}

func getFeeds(_ userId: Int) {
    VNetwork.getFeeds(userId) { feeds in
        self.feeds = feeds
        self.tableView.isHidden = self.feeds.count == 0
        self.configureCells()
        self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it's helped for me!

Comment: @ArtemVlasenko I was referring to the fact that you accepted an answer that just repeated what I have already suggested before.. so while there is no police here, it would be fair to accept mine (unless there is something I am not seeing that makes Timm’s answer better than mine)

Comment: @MilanNosáľ Ok, bro)

Answer (score 0):

Put refreshControl.endRefreshing() After tableView.reloadData() like this:

```
tableView.reloadData()
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this it's  work for me.

```
var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl!

override func viewDidLoad() {
        refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        refreshControl.tintColor = UIColor.white
        self.tblPartyList.addSubview(refreshControl)
        refreshControl.addTarget(self, action:#selector(handleRefresh(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
}
@objc func handleRefresh(_ refreshControl: UIRefreshControl) {

}
```